# How can I create a ComplexFilterPart using SSJS / API in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, api

I am creating a Landing Page in Marketing Cloud and would like to use the API to query an Object and filter by a specific property, returning only relevant results.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following code to start your API call.  This example uses a EmailSendDefinition Object and a few properties.  Refer here [Marketing Cloud Technical Library](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/emailsenddefinition/) for more information on the properties available. Make sure to include the Property that you need to filter by (in this case, "ModifiedDate")

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "EmailSendDefinition");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CustomerKey");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Name");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "EmailSubject")
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "SendDefinitionList");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "DeliveryProfile.CustomerKey");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "SenderProfile.CustomerKey");;
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "IsMultipart");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CategoryID");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "CreatedDate");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ModifiedDate");
```

Then use this code to create the ComplexFilterPart (which consists of two SimpleFilterParts)

```
        //"From" date
        var sfp1 = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp1, "Property", "ModifiedDate");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp1, "SimpleOperator", "greaterThanOrEqual");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp1, "Value", "2015-08-27T00:00:00.000");

        //"To" date
        var sfp2 = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp2, "Property", "ModifiedDate");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp2, "SimpleOperator", "lessThanOrEqual");
        Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp2, "Value", "2015-08-28T00:00:00.000");


        //Adding two Simple filters together to create a Complex filter
        var cfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart");
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "LeftOperand", sfp1);
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "LogicalOperator", "AND");     
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "RightOperand", sfp2);

        //Add the Complex filter to the RetrieveRequest
        Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", cfp);
```

Now perform the retrieve:

```
        var retrieveStatus = [0, 0, 0];
        var retrieveResult = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, retrieveStatus);

        Write(Stringify(retrieveResult));

</script>
```

This returns a JSON object of all EmailSendDefinition Objects (User Initiated Sends) with a ModifiedDate between 27 August 2015 and 28 August 2015.

For more information on the operators available, refer here: [Marketing Cloud Simple Operators](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/simpleoperators/)